# CSS Floating/Wrapping issue

Tags: css

I'm not sure how to explain this properly, but I'm trying to get a list of elements to wrap around a block.

Here is an image of what I mean:  [image]

The code is below. It floats left correctly if there are only 2 blocks, but when I add more it drops to below the welcome block (as in the image).

The design shows 2 blocks next to the welcome box, then 3 underneath. So in the image the 3rd block should sit under the welcome block, and subsequent blocks will continue normal (3 blocks per line).

CSS

```
#welcome-block {
float: left;
width: 300px;
background: #fff;
}

#bingo-offers {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
    .bingo-offer {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    }
        .bingo-offer ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div>
        <div id="welcome-block">
            <h2>Welcome to Zesty Bingo</h2>
            <p>Zesty Bingo is the home of FREE Bingo!</p>
            <p>We have a huge selection of Bingo games to choose. Simple find a game, and click play. It’s as simple
            as that.</p>

            <p>Ensure you click the read more link on each game to find out more details and customer reviews on all
            of our hosted games.</p>

            <p>Good Luck and we wish you wealth and happiness from all the Zesty Bingo team.</p>
        </div>

        <ul id="bingo-offers">
            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these:

```
<ul id="bingo-offers">

<li class="bingo-offer">
```

to these

```
<div id="bingo-offers">

<div class="bingo-offer">
```

UPDATE: Don't use `<div id="bingo-offers">` at all, just remove the tags there. Put the `<div class="bingo-offer">`s directly after the `<div id="welcome-block">`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tWMG/2/)

Comment: Ah that does work, there must be a way to get it to work with the list in it's current state.

Comment: That can be made with the list, however I did it this way because otherwise the later bingo-offers wouldn't wrap under the welcome-box.

Comment: Removing the float from bingo-offers worked. Allowed me to keep them as a list. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using `<ul id="bingo-offers">`

The `<ul>` itself is floating left but it is also `width:100%;`

If you were to remove the `<ul id="bingo-offers">` it might work better. Also you could change the `<li>` to `<div>`

Try this: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gk7bJ/)

Answer (score 0):

set width

```
#bingo-offers {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width:XXX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#welcome-block {
float: left;
width: 300px;
background: #fff;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#bingo-offers {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

#bingo-offers > li.bingo-offer{
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Apply above css. To see how to done visit below link.

```
http://sandalwoodinteriors.com/view.php?name=Bed%20Room%20Set
```